# buildbot not updating mercurial to latest head on forcebuilds

Tags: testing, mercurial, buildbot

I have some scripts run after changes are pushed through a timer and they worked fine in using the proper head, but a force build *after* those had completed did not succeed. The same slave is being used. Here is a wrapper command for pull/update in `master.cfg`,

```
def repo_update( conf ):
    repo = "ssh://buildbot@repo//Users/buildbot/repo"
    repository = Mercurial( repourl=repo, branchType='inrepo', defaultBranch='devel')
    conf.addStep( repository )
    return
```

In the log it executes the following commands,

```
/usr/local/bin/hg pull --verbose ssh://buildbot@repo//Users/buildbot/repo
/usr/local/bin/hg identify --num --branch
/usr/local/bin/hg paths default
/usr/local/bin/hg update --clean --repository build --rev 15f87a21bf8aa00d642c2ebbd73a6da161815eaa
/usr/local/bin/hg identify --id --debug
```

Both logs have the same list of commands and they execute fine. But, in the forcebuild the script has a different argument for `--rev` --an older head; I'm not even sure where it is grabbing that number, it's not mentioned anywhere else in the script or logs, must be coming from the server, but how do I specify the head or NOT specify it? Am I adding the proper step to the repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem until I added **alwaysUseLatest=True**. In your case I suppose you could use:

```
repository = Mercurial(
    repourl=repo, 
    branchType='inrepo',
    defaultBranch='devel', 
    alwaysUseLatest=True
)
```

Comment: I need to verify this, but it looks legit. I wont be working on the tests until next week, when I'll approve the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `--rev` argument comes either from the revision, or if that is empty, the branch specified in the source stamp. It is possible to specify either of these things when force building.

On the other hand, if you press the rebuild button, when looking at a particular build, the revision built in that particular build is used in the forced build.

Comment: Nope, I clicked "rebuild" from the page that shows the results of a previous build, where it explicitly states a rebuild will be from the latest revision.